# Concatenate columns on multiple lines in a cell in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am creating a Windows Form in VB.NET and have a datagridview set to read-only with two columns.

The datagridview is connected to a SQL Server database and I am referencing two tables. The first column is an image and the second column is a concatenation of 4 columns: Rank, LName, Title, FName. I have the second column set to wrap, but I actually need the Rank to be displayed above the name, all in the same cell.

Example:

---

(Rank) HR Director

(Name) Doe, Jane

---

Currently displays as :

---

HR Director Doe,

Jane

---

Here is what my current code looks like:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class some_digital_directory

Dim conDatabase As New SqlConnection("Server=servername;Database=dbname;Integrated Security=True")

Private Sub some_digital_directory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim comSQL As SqlCommand = conDatabase.CreateCommand()

    comSQL.CommandText = "SELECT B.IMAGE01, A.RANK + ' ' + A.LNAME + ' ' + A.TITLE + ', ' + A.FNAME AS NAME
        FROM EMPMAST AS A LEFT JOIN PICTURE AS B ON A.PERNO=B.PERNO
        WHERE A.HIDE <>'TRUE' AND NAME <>' '
        ORDER BY A.LNAME, A.FNAME, A.MNAME"

    Dim adptSQL As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim tblEmployees As New DataTable()

    adptSQL.SelectCommand = comSQL
    conDatabase.Open()
    adptSQL.Fill(tblEmployees)
    conDatabase.Close()

    dgvEmployees.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    dgvEmployees.RowTemplate.Height = 150
    dgvEmployees.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
    dgvEmployees.DataSource = tblEmployees

    Dim imgPerson As New DataGridViewImageColumn()

    imgPerson = dgvEmployees.Columns(0)
    imgPerson.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
```

Comment: You don't need `conDatabase.Open()` and the corresponding close because the `Fill` command does that for you (it leaves the connection state the same as it was before). You should not create the connection just once - it should be created (New) each time it's going to be used and then call `.Dispose()` on it. You should also use `comSQL.Dispose()` when that is finished with. It helps keep everything tidy and without memory leaks.

Comment: So you're saying put the comSQL.Dispose () where I have the close?

Comment: Even better is to use `Using` which will take care of the disposal even if something goes wrong. I edited my answer to show where you'd do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a CRLF when you compose the string, so instead of

```
A.RANK + ' ' + A.LNAME + ' ' + A.TITLE + ', ' + A.FNAME AS NAME
```

you would have

```
A.RANK + ' ' + A.LNAME + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + A.TITLE + ', ' + A.FNAME AS NAME
```

Although it seems to me that you have the TITLE in the LNAME column and vice versa.

**EDIT:** In light of your comment, you may want:

```
A.RANK + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + A.TITLE + ', ' + A.FNAME AS NAME
```

So you would end up with:

```
Dim connStr As String = "Server=servername;Database=dbname;Integrated Security=True"

Private Sub some_digital_directory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Using conDatabase As New SqlConnection(connStr)

        Using comSQL As SqlCommand = conDatabase.CreateCommand()

            comSQL.CommandText = "SELECT B.IMAGE01, A.RANK + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + A.TITLE + ', ' + A.FNAME AS NAME
    FROM EMPMAST AS A LEFT JOIN PICTURE AS B ON A.PERNO=B.PERNO
    WHERE A.HIDE <>'TRUE' AND NAME <>' '
    ORDER BY A.LNAME, A.FNAME, A.MNAME"

            Dim adptSQL As New SqlDataAdapter()
            Dim tblEmployees As New DataTable()

            adptSQL.SelectCommand = comSQL
            adptSQL.Fill(tblEmployees)

        End Using

    End Using

    ' rest of code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Title is where Sr and Jr are placed for the last name.